How to change ownership of a video I uploaded to Youtube?
I uploaded a video to a YouTube channel that belongs to my Google account. I want to transfer ownership to the channel of another Google account (of my wife). How can I do this?

You cannot directly transfer the video or any of the existing metrics (eg. view count) to her account.
You will need to upload the video to her channel in much the same way you did originally on yours.
